# Converting PDF Byte Array to jpg image in c#

Tags: c#, image, pdf

I am trying to convert PDF Byte Array to image in a project.Is there any way to convert pdf byte array to image without using any external libraries like Ghost script,PDFRasterizer.NET 3.0 etc

```
 using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(@"D:\FileFolder\file.pdf")) // in file
{
      var bytes = new byte[file.Length];
      file.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

       byte[] pngBytes = bytes; // need to convert image type and assign
       using (var outFile = File.Create(@"D:\FileFolder\file.png")) // out file
       {
             outFile.Write(pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
       }}
```

Comment: PDFs and PNGs are completely different file formats. You will need to have some code to do this and while you could write it all yourself rather than using external libraries this is almost certainly not a good idea (because it will be hard, it will take a lot of time and you'll probably make something worse than in external libraries).

Comment: Technically it's possible but in practice I don't think that it's a good idea. You will have to write the whole parser of the PDF engine to do that.